# Grails 3.1.16 Interceptors not filtering on method

Tags: grails, grails3, grails-3.1

I'm trying to use Grails interceptors to match specific uri having specific HTTP methods. The method argument of the match method is however ignored, despite the fact that I upgraded my Grails version from 3.1.1 to [3.1.16, where that issue should be fixed](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9905).

An simplified version of my code would be:

```
@GrailsCompileStatic
class MyInterceptor {

    int order = HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE

    MyInterceptor () {
        match(uri: '/api/domain/*', method: 'PUT')
        match(uri: '/api/domain/*', method: 'DELETE')
        match(uri: '/api/domain/*', method: 'POST')
    }
}
```

With the following interceptor test:

```
@TestFor(MyInterceptor)
class MyInterceptorSpec extends Specification {

    @Unroll
    def "it matches '#method #uri'"() {
        when: "A request matches the interceptor"
        withRequest(uri: uri, method: method)

        then:"The interceptor does match"
        interceptor.doesMatch()

        where:
        uri             | method
        '/api/domain/1' | 'PUT'
        '/api/domain/1' | 'POST'
        '/api/domain/1' | 'DELETE'
    }

    @Unroll
    def "it does not match '#method #uri'"() {
        when:
        withRequest(uri: uri, method: method)

        then:
        !interceptor.doesMatch()

        where:
        uri             | method
        '/api/domain'   | 'GET'
        '/api/domain/1' | 'GET' // failing test
    }

}
```

How can I ensure that the interceptor match uris only for given HTTP methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible by default in Grails.

Looking at the code of the UrlMappingMatcher we can see that when we define a matching rule with an uri, the method part is ignored:

```
@Override
Matcher matches(Map arguments) {
    if(arguments.uri) {
        uriPatterns << arguments.uri.toString()
    }
    else {
        controllerRegex = regexMatch( arguments, "controller")
        actionRegex = regexMatch( arguments, "action")
        namespaceRegex = regexMatch( arguments, "namespace")
        methodRegex = regexMatch( arguments, "method")
    }
    return this
}

@Override
Matcher excludes(Map arguments) {
    if(arguments.uri) {
        uriExcludePatterns << arguments.uri.toString()
    }
    else {
        def exclude = new MapExclude()
        exclude.controllerExcludesRegex = regexMatch( arguments, "controller", null)
        exclude.actionExcludesRegex = regexMatch( arguments, "action", null)
        exclude.namespaceExcludesRegex = regexMatch( arguments, "namespace", null)
        exclude.methodExcludesRegex = regexMatch( arguments, "method", null)
        excludes << exclude
    }
    return this
}
```

You can however create a subclass of UrlMappingMatcher that takes into account the method even when an uri is defined, and use it instead of the regular one in your Interceptor:

```
// in MyInterceptor.groovy
Matcher match(Map arguments) {
    // use your own implementation of the UrlMappingMatcher
    def matcher = new MethodFilteringUrlMappingMatcher(this)
    matcher.matches(arguments)
    matchers << matcher
    return matcher
}
```